# SEARCH_LONG_PRESS calls onResume for separate activity, sometimes

Tags: android, android-intent

So, I have a package with an activity that runs when android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS is fired (LongPressSearchKey.java).  When called, LongPressSearchKey.java calls another activity to create and save a file.  The same package has a third activity that displays a list of all the saved files (AppWindow.java).

Here's the situation:  When the SEARCH_LONG_PRESS activity is called, I want the focus on the screen not to change.  I've successfully accomplished this by calling finish() when the LongPressSearchKey.java logic is complete.  It gets focus for a split-second and then ends, returning to whatever I was already doing.  However, if the onCreate() method in AppWindow.java has been previously called, then any subsequent SEARCH_LONG_PRESS action will also (for no apparent reason) call the onResume() method for AppWindow.java.  This brings up the list of saved files, which I don't want to see.  Is there an inherent reason for this behavior?  If so, then I guess I'll have to try to kill AppWindow.java when SEARCH_LONG_PRESS is fired.

The basic code is shown below, which I stripped down for troubleshooting purposes.  Even with this minimal logic, AppWindow.java still gets called by SEARCH_LONG_PRESS.

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:debuggable="true" >

    <activity
        android:name=".LongPressSearchKey"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH_LONG_PRESS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".AppWindow"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>

...
```

LongPressSearchKey.java

```
...

public class LongPressSearchKey extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        MyClass.makeFile(this);
        finish();
    }
}
```

AppWindow.java

```
...

public class AppWindow extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was about to post a very similar question. If you solved this issue, could you share your solution to it please? I'm going to have to control the SEARCH_LONG_PRESS activity using 'markers' in onCreate, onPause & onResume so I know what previously (if anything) happened - but I can't help thinking there must be a better implementation/solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I wish I could tell you that the issue was solved, but I've just been calling the finish() method in the separate activity (AppWindow.java).  This is a pretty ugly solution.  Maybe if you post your question, then someone will respond.